# Text inside div not receiving margin or padding given to div

Tags: html, css, margin

This is my HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id='content'>
            hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi<br />hi
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
html, body, #content {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: red;
}

#content {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Now, how come my content div does not go all the way to the bottom of the page and how come the 100px margin does it make the words inside content be 100px from the bottom of the screen?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/npwp0nr2/2/

Edit: The content should have a height which takes up the entire screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation

Let's see what's happening here:

- The `margin-bottom: 100px` creates a gap underneath `#content` on the *outside*
- The `padding-bottom: 100px` creates a gap *inside* `#content`
- The `height: 100%` is giving a fixed height that is determined based on the height of the viewport when the page is rendered

This is made more obvious if you set `overflow: auto` on `#content`. "Show code snippet" and run the code snippet below:

- Scroll the `#content` div to the bottom, you can see the bottom padding creating a gap.
- The bottom margin is the gap underneath the content border

```css
html,
body,
#content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
}
#content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='content'>
    hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
  </div>
</body>
```

So that explains your current behaviour, but...

## How do I keep the div stretched to the bottom?

To have the content div stretch to the bottom of the viewport regardless of content:

- `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` incorporates padding and borders into the height calculation
- `html,body { height: 100%; }` allows child elements of the body element to have percentage height properties
- `#content` is given a **min-height** of 100% which will stretch
- The default margin on the body is removed with `margin: 0` (this can be replaced with padding, if required)

CSS / HTML / Demo

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0;
}
#content {
    border: 5px solid black;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Height doesn't respect percentage values. The height of an element is determined by either the height of it's content, or an explicit value. Typically, setting height on an element (especially one being used as a container) should be avoided, and the body and HTML tags don't need it ever. Remove the first rule entirely, and give the content div the 100px width rule, and it achieves what I think you're after.

```
body {
  background-color: red;
}
#content {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nxu41721/1/)

Comment: is there any way for content to have a height which takes up the entire screen? because when I remove that about of 'hi <br />'s then the content does not have a height which takes up the entire screen. http://jsfiddle.net/nxu41721/5/

Answer (score 0):

`height:100%` doesn't do anything useful in CSS. You have to give it a definite height or simply let the content cause the height to increase. Take out `height:100%`.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you want the content div to fill the whole page height and apply a padding of 100px?

Sorry but within the same div the browser will not discriminate and cut off content because you cannot add negative padding, it will just continue to expand off the page. To illustrate i altered your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/npwp0nr2/4/

try uncommenting the `height:100%;` line in css and seeing what happens. You'll find it will expand the div to 100% height but again you cannot use negative padding.

Comment: The only way to add space only if the content reaches close to the bottom and keep the height at 100% is to dynamically calculate the height of the content within the div after page load, something that html cannot do, you will need javascript.